# Reset counter after everyday Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, counter, reset

I am trying to make a billing menu for a software. What i am trying to do is, I want to assign a bill id to each bill using the date, say 24/11/2022 will be converted as 24112022. This will be followed by a count as: 24112022-**01**. I want this counter to reset whenever the date changes. I can't figure it out. Any solutions?
Here is the code I am using to get the date values and use them as my bill id

```
LocalDate date=LocalDate.now();
        int d=date.getDayOfMonth();
        int m=date.getMonthValue();
        int y=date.getYear();
        billId=String.valueOf(d)+String.valueOf(m)+String.valueOf(y)+counter++;
```

Comment: You have to save the previous date as a `LocalDate` and do a comparison between the saved `LocalDate` and the current `LocalDate`.  If the current `LocalDate` is greater, reset the counter to 1 and save the current date as the previous date.

Answer (score 0):

"I want this counter to reset whenever the date changes."
Think analytically (re-framing the question for this context):
a) You want a counter to reset when the date changes
b) When the date changes, you want the counter reset
c) Upon a data change, reset the counter.

So, you may want to occasionally check the time and see if it has changed (having a stored value to compare against) or overwrite an existing method that changes the day so that it would also reset the value.